# Action Bar Overflow not using Three-Dot icon

Tags: android

I can't seem to determine why my overflow button is not the three-dot icon. It uses what seems to be a dropdown button (down arrow icon).

How come most of the applications I found uses the three-dot icon for the overflow. Here's my styles.xml so far.

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CncaActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CncaActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CncaActionBarTab</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/CncaActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="buttonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="CncaActionBarTab" parent="@android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_tab</item>
</style>

<style name="CncaActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still can't post a screenshot. But I found the png image in the android sdk library. In my directory, it can be found here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-18\data\res\ Filename is ic_menu_more.png. I found the three-dot overflow images which I think refers to a different theme. But I don't know yet the specific theme to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I just needed to use Theme.Holo styling. This used the three-dot icon.